# all combinations of word list A with word List b and word list C while maintaing the order of said listed words

Tags: python, powershell

Total noob here 07. I am hoping someone may be able to help me here. I am trying to generate a word list that will combine 3 word list with all potential combinations while maintaining the order of said lists I am impartial to which language would be used I have have used python and Powershell

I have searched google and although i am able to combine all of this i cant seem to figure out how to maintain the order

Examples
wordlist A

```
Alica
Mike
John
```

word list b

```
bike
car
truck
```

word list C

```
123
321
231
```

expected output will include all combinations

```
Alicabike321
Miketruck123
Johncar231
Alicacar231
Miketbike123
Johntruck321.....
```

so in effect, word list A is the anchor to b and b to c if that makes sense
any help would be greatly appreciated..

Bal33p.

Comment: FYI it's a good habit to write some code AND post it in your Q

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
listA = ['Alica','Mike','John']
listB = ['bike','car','truck']
listC = ['123','321','231']

output_list = []
for item1 in listA:
    for item2 in listB:
        for item3 in listC:
            output_list.append(item1+item2+item3)
print(output_list)
```

The solution is as simple as iterating through each element in each list in the specified order and just add the result to a temporary list. Finally, you can use or print the result list variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with a nested `for` loop. Python example:

Start by creating the lists:

```
wordlist_A = ['Alica', 'Mike', 'John']
wordlist_B = ['bike', 'car', 'truck']
wordlist_C = ['123', '321', '231']
```

Then write the nested `for` loop like this:

```
for word_C in wordlist_C:
    for word_B in wordlist_B:
        for word_A in wordlist_A:
            print(word_A+word_B+word_C)
```

What we're doing is, for every word_C, going through every word_B, and for every word_B, going through every word_A.

Then, in the final `print` statement, we establish that the order is `word_a`, `word_B`, `word_C`.

You can switch the order of the for loops if you want, what that'll do is change the order each word combination appears in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output order can't be achieved with stacked for commands as however you order the for they are iterated one after the other.

Here a powershell version

```
ForEach($name in 'Alica', 'Mike', 'John'){
  ForEach($vehicle in 'bike', 'car', 'truck'){
    ForEach($number in '123', '321', '231'){
      "{0}{1}{2}" -f $name,$vehicle,$number
    }
  }
}
```

Returning this output:

```
Alicabike123
Alicabike321
Alicabike231
Alicacar123
Alicacar321
Alicacar231
Alicatruck123
Alicatruck321
Alicatruck231
Mikebike123
Mikebike321
...
```

**EDIT To read the wordlists from files:**

```
ForEach($name in (Get-Content 'wordListA.txt)){
  ForEach($vehicle in (Get-Content 'wordListB.txt)){
    ForEach($number in (Get-Content 'wordListC.txt)){
      "{0}{1}{2}" -f $name,$vehicle,$number
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, this is the exact output I am looking for. I am thinking that I can't just replace the iterated Alica, Mike, John with an actual wordlistA.txt file containing said names?

Comment: See changed answer.